# AHK is lagging when I do specific code; Do I need a delay of some sort?

Tags: autohotkey

```
#if, GetKeyState("XButton1", "P")
    *WheelUp::click
#if

#if, GetKeyState("XButton1", "P")
    *WheelDown::click
#if
```

This makes the scroll wheel click when XButton1 is held down, but the problem is that it becomes very laggy after using it for about 10+ seconds. I usually do a little less than 20CPS (Clicks per second).

Comment: Does `XButton1 & WheelUp::Click` lag for you?

Comment: Yes I think that's what lags it. I can hold both and click manually and not lag (with about 12CPS) but with the program I can't.

Comment: Instead of using `#If . . . `, have you tried using `XButton1 & WheelUp::Click` all by itself? It seems to work well on my machine.

Comment: If I do that then I won't be able to use other keys (I think), I want to be able to press wasd & others while I hold XButton1 and mousewheel

Comment: I just tested it and it appears to work fine while holding other keys. Specifically, I was holding the W-key and did XButton1+WheelUp and it produced the desired effect. For reference, I used this code: `XButton1 & WheelUp::MsgBox`.